# Hierarchical Expectation Maximization

Tags: hierarchical-bayesian, expectation-maximization

Let us assume we have a generative model $y = g(\theta,x)$, where $\theta$ is a set of parameters, and $x$ is a set of latent variables. Given a datapoint $y$, I need to update the parameters $\theta$ to maximize the model evidence

$$p(y,\theta) = \int_x p(y \mid x,\theta) p(x,\theta)dx.$$

This integral is, however, often expensive/intractable to compute. An approximate solution can be found via expectation maximization: during the E-step, we infer the best possible values $x$ that maximize the model evidence, and then we use them to update the parameters $\theta$, in what is called the M-step.

Now, let us assume that our model is a hierarchical generative model with $L$ layers, i.e., $x = (x_0,\dots, x_L)$. Here, we have

$$ p(x_0,\dots, x_L) = p(L)\prod_{l<L}p(x_l \mid x_{l+1}).$$

I'm noting that, in practice, performing disjoints E-steps that depend on the level of the hierarchy, improves the performance. More in detail, instead of performing the E-step on all the parameters $x = (x_0,\dots, x_L)$ simultaneously, if I perform $L$ different E-steps, one per layer, starting from layer $0$, I have better performance. So, let us assume we are given the datapoint $y$, we set $x_0 = y$ and:

1. Update $x_1$ to maximize $p(y \mid x_1)$
2. Update $x_2$ to maximize $p(x_1 \mid x_2)$

....

L. Update $x_L$ to maximize $p(x_{L-1} \mid x_{L})$

L+1. Update all the parameters $\theta$ according to the newly computed $x_1, \dots, x_L$.

Here, points $1$ to $L$ all correspond to the E-step, where $L+1$ corresponds to the M-step.

Q: So, my question is: is there a variation of the EM-algorithm in the literature that is similar to the one I have proposed? Does it have convergence guarantees (so, something like: It converges to the same minimum of the standard EM)?

Comment: [Meng & van Dyk (1997)](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Courses/956/Resource/HiddenMarkovModels/EM/MengVanDyk97.pdf) contains similar variations on EM.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry but the paper is a little hard to grasp for me. Could you point out which method is it? In the paper, they talk about this Alternate Expectation-Conditional Maximization. Is it the one? And why is it similar and not equivalent? Thanks!